# Temporal workflow hardware constraints for low latency

Tags: low-latency, temporal-workflow

I have recently started reading about temporal for use in my company's project. I have built an in-house orchestrator for short lived tasks which is able to support 100 tps with 8 gb heap and 4 cores. I am running on a oracle database with 16gb and 4 cores.

My in-house orchestrator uses kafka as an event source and a trie to model a DSL using which the next service to be invoked is decided. On comparing my simple orchestrator with temporal I see that while temporal has more features for resiliency and instrumentation of workflows it seems to be taking too much hardware and does not seem to have a focus on low latency. Is my observation correct and should I look for a combination of my low latency orchestrator with temporal or am I missing something here.

Comment: Can I achieve 100 tps of execution for executing the same workflow with different data points and different workflow with unique data points with the above configuration ? Can temporal support Oracle database also?

Comment: @mfateev would request you to comment on this

Comment: I remember last year they list the situation which Temporal is not suitable for. And the first one they listed is low latency task(realtime). Don't know why they took it down......

Comment: In their poll activity/workflow approach, the default is to wait for 5 second. Then 
 it will disconnect and reconnect. Maybe they want to control the number of alive connection. You can make the latency lower by increasing worker and worker thread. But it definitely is not a permanent solution